# What does the sync and syncFs of SequenceFile.Writer means?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sequencefile

Environment: Hadoop `0.20.2-cdh3u5`

I am trying to upload log data (10G) to HDFS with a customized tool which using SequenceFile.Writer.

```
SequenceFile.Writer w = SequenceFile.createWriter(
                hdfs,
                conf,
                p,
                LongWritable.class,
                Text.class,
                4096,
                hdfs.getDefaultReplication(),
                hdfs.getDefaultBlockSize(),
                compressionType,
                codec,
                null,
                new Metadata());
```

During the uploading process, if the tool crashed (without invoke the close() method explicitly), will the log that has been uploaded lost?

Should I invoke sync() or syncFs() timely, what do the two methods means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, probably.

`sync()` create a sync point. As stated in the book "Hadoop- The Definitive Guide" by Tom White (Cloudera)

> a sync point is a point in the stream which can used by to
>   resynchronize with a record boundary if the reader is "lost" - for
>   example after seeking to an arbitrary position on the stream.

Now the implementation of `syncFS()` is pretty simple:

```
   public void syncFs() throws IOException {
      if (out != null) {
        out.sync();                               // flush contents to file system
      }
    }
```

where `out` is a `FSDataOutputStream`. Again, in the same book is stated:

> HDFS provides a method for forcing all buffers to be synchronized  to
>   the datanodes via the `sync()`  method on `FSDataOutputStream`. After
>   a successful call return from `sync()` HDFS garantees that the data
>   written up to that point in the file is persisted and visible to all
>   readers. In the event of a crash (of the client or HDFS), the data
>   will not be lost.

But a footnote warns to look to bug [HDFS-200](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-200), since the visibility mentioned above was not always not always honored.